# When Kafka connection is idle?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I faced an issue that when my Kafka consumers read some topic and it does not have messages for some time then Kafka thinks that connection is idle as I understood. I saw these trace logs:

```
About to close the idle connection from 2147482646 due to being idle for 540005 millis
Node 2147482646 disconnected.
```

But why it's idle? I have a default config connections.max.idle.ms: 9 mins, also heartbeat checks every 5 secs, session ms is 30 sec. As I understood maybe Kafka does not recognize heartbeats as "actions". Okay then we have regular poll() calls and as for me, it's an action even if I got 0 messages. But then I found an idea that connection is idle if nothing was written to the TCP socket for some period of time. So if my Kafka gets nothing within 9 mins (messages) then it's idle? Is it the truth? Or how then kafka recognizes that connection is idle?

UPD:
Poll is an action no matter how many messages you got. I ran kafka locally and started debugging with CONNECTIONS_MAX_IDLE_MS_CONFIG=5000 and I found out that my kafka consumer created 2 different connections and then one of them after some time was not used for 5 secs and it caused the closing of the connection. so why it happens that one connection was not used for a long time? Since I tried 10secs and the same. On my prod config is default 9 mins but it happens.
And what's interesting after I faced it 1 time then kafka recreates a connection and everything is fine. But maybe if its a group coordinator then it makes kafka rebalance and create all connections from scratch an issue appears again.

kafka-clients version 3.2.0. My code for testing:

```
    Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);
    logger.info("test");
    String bootstrapServers = "127.0.0.1:9092";
    String grp_id = "test";
    String topic = "test";

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, grp_id);
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.CONNECTIONS_MAX_IDLE_MS_CONFIG, "5000");

    KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);

    consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topic));

    while (true) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
            System.out.println("Key: " + record.key() + ", Value:" + record.value());
            System.out.println("Partition:" + record.partition() + ",Offset:" + record.offset());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show code that performs reading

Comment: @DmitryPukhov added testing code to the question

Comment: @MykytaPiddubskiy Hi, I got the similar issue. Did you find any clues?